# do-while loopwith 3 conditions

Tags: java, while-loop, do-while

I'm in a stuck with do-while looping that requires looping with do-while until users input one of three correct strings

I've tried with this

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String motor = "motor";
    String mobil = "mobil";
    String kosong = "";
    String baru = "baru";
    int tahun = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);

do {
        inputVehicleType();
        vehicleCondition = input.next();
    }
while (!(vehicleCondition.equals(motor)) || (vehicleCondition.equals(mobil)) || (vehicleCondition.equals(kosong)));

System.out.println("SUCCED");

private static void inputVehicleType() {
    System.out.println(Constant.HEADER);
    System.out.println("Input Jenis Kendaraan Mobil/Motor --> (jenis [motor/mobil])");
    titleFooter();
}
```

with that syntax it only retrieve (vehicleCondition.equals(motor).
My expected result was it can retrieve (vehicleCondition.equals(motor), (vehicleCondition.equals(mobil), (vehicleCondition.equals(kosong).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you remove the excess parentheses it may be easier to spot that you have `while (!a || b || c)` instead of `while (!(a || b || c))`.

```
do {
    ...
} while (!(vehicleCondition.equals(motor) ||
           vehicleCondition.equals(mobil) ||
           vehicleCondition.equals(kosong)));
```

Or, equivalently via [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), `while (!a && !b && !c)`:

```
do {
    ...
} while (!vehicleCondition.equals(motor) &&
         !vehicleCondition.equals(mobil) &&
         !vehicleCondition.equals(kosong));
```

Answer (score 3):

You have made a mistake in your while logic expression

should be:

```
while (!((vehicleCondition.equals(motor)) || (vehicleCondition.equals(mobil)) || (vehicleCondition.equals(kosong))));
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct condition would be:

```
while (!(vehicleCondition.equals(motor) || 
         vehicleCondition.equals(mobil) || 
         vehicleCondition.equals(kosong)));
```

i.e. you should stay in the loop as long as `vehicleCondition` is not equal to one of the 3 expected values.

Answer (score 0):

Make a method to check the condition:

```
private static boolean isValidVehiculeCondition(String vc) {
    return !Arrays.asList("motor", "mobil", "baru").contains(vc.toLowerCase());
}
```

Then loop while it returns true (ie: input is not valid)

```
do {
    inputVehicleType();
} while(isNotValidVehiculeCondition(input.next()));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a little parenthesis mistake in your code. You need to add an extra parenthesis around not operator. Your condition should be

```
while (!(
  (vehicleCondition.equals(motor)) ||
  (vehicleCondition.equals(mobil)) || (vehicleCondition.equals(kosong))
));
```